# Using # and " in ColdFusion query gives error

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am trying to insert the following string in my DB using CF query: `Aman#30 is "OK"`

But I get the error "Invalid construct: Either argument or name is missing."

On further investigation I found that this happens only if I use # or " in the string.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yep. We need to see your code, because usually # signs only need to be escaped when hard coded. The behavior is different when a # sign is contained in a form field for example.

Comment: FYI - here's a pretty good article on when to use pound signs. it will help clear this up a little bit for you :) http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/10/when.do.i.use.pound.signs

Answer (score 9):

You'll most likely need to escape the pound-sign and the quotes. For example:

```
<CFSET yourstring = "Aman##30 is ""OK""" />

<CFQUERY result="qRes" datasource="#yourDSN#">
  INSERT INTO `yourtable`
  (`yourstringfield`)
  VALUES
  (<CFQUERYPARAM value="#yourstring#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />)
</CFQUERY>
```